# How do I scroll the page to the top after the fragment identifier pulls the page down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not trying to prevent the fragment identifier from working. I want the page to go back to the top after it goes down.

This question is asked for the purposes of using jQuery's UI tabs. You need the id to be set on the tab content div, so that jQuery knows which tab to open.

The fragment identifier will open the tab that it is set to, but it also scrolls the page down to the tab's content.

On a page with the tab close to the top, and barely any headers, I wish to keep my page at the top, not scroll down ~150 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript's onscroll event, we can see when the page scrolls.

Side note - Since I only have one scenario, I verify that my fragment identifier is what it should be.

We need to then keep a count of when the page scrolls. The page should only be set to the top at the beginning, otherwise the user wouldn't be able to scroll. Thus, check the scroll count for 1, and then move the page to the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollCount = 0;
    window.onscroll = function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        if (hash === "chats") {
            scrollCount++;
        }
        if (scrollCount === 1) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }
</script>
```